# Mutual difference of vectors squared, does it have a name?

Tags: summation, sums-of-squares

Given a set of $n$ vectors $\def\vv{\vec{v}} \vv_i$ with the additional property that they all have the same absolute value $||\vv_i||=c$, define the average of the vectors as $\vv = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \vv_i$.

If all $\vv_i$ are identical we have $||\vv|| = c$, but if they all have different directions, a not to complicated derivation yields

$$ c^2 -  ||\vv||^2 = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i<j}^n ||\vv_i-\vv_j||^2 .$$

The sum on the right side is the average mutual delta squared of the individual vectors.

It vaguely reminds me of variance, which it is obviously not.
Does the formula have a name? Does it appear prominently in another context?

Comment: Thanks for downvoting, telling me there is something wrong with this question. Eagerly awaiting your comment to explain how I can improve it.

Comment: I suspect (but don't know as it wasn't me) the issue is with $\overrightarrow{v}^2$, which is not standard for any known vector operation. If you mean dot product, then $\overrightarrow{v} \cdot \overrightarrow{v}$ or $\Vert \overrightarrow{v} \Vert^2$ fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I learned that the right hand side is [identical to the variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Discrete_random_variable) of the $\\v_i$.